# PUT request - google script url fetch issue

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, put, urlfetch

I'm having issues to use the put function. Anyone can find out the error?
Thank you

CURL --

```
curl --request PUT \
     --url https://open-api.guesty.com/v1/listings/XXXXXX/custom-fields \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'authorization: BEARERXXX' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --data '
{
     "customFields": [
          {
               "fieldId": "5f744b491af840002ca636a2",
               "value": "Door code"
          }
     ]
}
'
```

My google script:

```
function putlistingcustomfield (){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('get_token');// You can change the sheets name here to match your needs
  var code = sheet.getRange("A18").getValue();

  const myHeaders2 = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: code,
  };
var data = {
    'customFields': {
      'fieldId': '639cdb92e128c3002a11b186',
      'value': 'test'
    },
  
};

    const options = {
    method: 'PUT', 
    headers: myHeaders2,
    followRedirects: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
  };

  const url = 'https://open-api.guesty.com/v1/listings/XXXXXX/custom-fields';
  let response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response2);

    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('write');// You can change the sheets name here to match your needs
    var cell2 = sheet2.getRange("A10");
      cell2.setValue(response2);

  };
```

I'm trying to push data using the PUT request from google script, GET is working, but can't figure out with PUT, how to implement it with google urlfetch

Answer (score 0):

From your showing sample curl command, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function putlistingcustomfield() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('get_token');
  var code = sheet.getRange("A18").getValue();
  const myHeaders2 = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: code, // Here, the value of `code` is required to be `Bearer XXX`. Please be careful about this.
  };
  var data = { 'customFields': [{ 'fieldId': '639cdb92e128c3002a11b186', 'value': 'test' }] }; // Modified
  const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: myHeaders2,
    // followRedirects: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json', // Modified
  };
  const url = 'https://open-api.guesty.com/v1/listings/XXXXXX/custom-fields';
  let response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response2);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('write');
  var cell2 = sheet2.getRange("A10");
  cell2.setValue(response2);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your token and the values of the request body are valid values. If an error related to them occurs, please confirm them again.
- From your error message, I noticed that it is required to modify the value of request body. So, I reflected in it.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hello! The curl function is working but the second script is not. Yes all ID, tokens, links etc work

Comment: @Paul Detrier Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the second script` of `but the second script is not.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? But, I think that the request of the script reflected my proposed modification is the same as your showing curl command. So, in this case, it is required to know your current script. By the way, I cannot know your current error message. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. Can you provide your current error message?

Comment: @Paul Detrier By the way, in your sample curl command, `--header 'authorization: BEARERXXX'` is used. I think that in this case, it might be `--header 'authorization: Bearer XXX'`. The space of ` ` is required to be included. If my understanding is correct, `code` of `Authorization: code,` is `Bearer XXX`? If the value of `code` is `XXX`, an error occurs. I'm worried about this. How about this? Unfortunately, I cannot know about this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Check my error message using your code: Exception: Request failed for https://open-api.guesty.com returned code 500. Truncated server response: child "customFields" fails because ["customFields" must be an array] (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
putlistingcustomfield @ put_listing_customsfields.gs:28

Comment: @Paul Detrier Thank you for replying. From your error message, I noticed that the value of the request body is required to be modified. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it again.